# Facebook Login throws "The user denied the app"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've been using the **Facebook SDK** integrated to an app to make login, so, when the user rejects the app, facebook sdk throws "The user denied the app".

I have been trying to handle this, making the session null, when the session get `CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED`, like this:

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
   Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
}

Session.setActiveSession(null);
```

But, when the user try to login again, the app allow to user enter without ask them if they allow the app.

Any suggestions what's going on? or what I should do?